# Could we know who published a post on WordPress?

Tags: user-roles, author, editor, publish

Besides knowing the author, could we know like which user with the Editor role published a post? Is this being tracked in the db?

Comment: Have you looked at revisions?

Comment: No, but as @JacobPeattie said, revisions can be helpful in this regard. But what about setups with revisions disabled? You could simply track the publisher by adding the user id as a post meta using `transition_post_status` hook.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I'm using custom post type from a plugin and I don't see any revision section on the right side of the editorial page. But perhaps I can try `transition_post_status` suggested by @Abhik

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this plugin to solve the issue - https://wordpress.org/plugins/stream/

Comment: That plugin is overkill for this simple issue.